# Creating a toString output from a LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I've been trying to figure out what exactly the LinkedList is called and supposed to be called as within toString2. I am still new to LinkedLists and don't quite understand them very clearly yet. This is what I've figured out, not really sure where to go from here since I'm confused on the LinkedList' name.

```
public String toString2(){
    String output = "";
    
    while(node != null){
    }

    return output;
}
```

Where do I get the `node` from? That’s the main thing that I’m confused about.

**Original Problem ([Source](https://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem/view/763?categoryid=37))**

Write a method toString2 that returns a string representation of the list, such as "[5, -2, 9]". Assume that you are adding this method to the LinkedIntList class as defined below:

```
public class LinkedIntList {
    private ListNode front;   // null for an empty list
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you are on the way. For iterating the nodes of the list you need to initialize `node` before your `while` loop and at the end of each iteration move it forward to the next node. You can find a million examples out there to see the details of how it’s done.

Comment: what do I get the "node" from? thats the main thing that im confused on.

Comment: You initialize `node` to `front` (the first node).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this to iterate and get the values?

```
  public String toString2(){
    String str = "";
    Node n = first;
    while( n != null ){
        str = str + n.getValue() + " ";
         n = n.getNext();
    }
    return str;
```

unless you provide complete code it would be hard to know what actual changes need to be made.